# Multiple Threads, how to create qt widgets properly

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have the follow constellation:

A qt gui thread with `MainWindow`

Another thread which essentially is a `CameraManager`...everytime a camera is added/removed the `MainWindow` will be informed.

It roughly looks like this:

Mainwindow derives from `ICameraAddedConsumer`

`MainWindow` implements `ConsumeCameraAdded` and creates widget inside this function. It subscribes itselv as a consumer to the `CameraManager`

CameraManager calls `ConsumeCameraAdded` of all it's consumers (`MainWindow`) when a new camera is added.

The problem is that CameraManager lives in a different thread and Qt will obviously complain about this since a widget is not created in the same thread as the mainwindow was.

Any suggestions how I can solve this?

Comment: I'd expect signals and slots to take care of that inter-thread communication. You don't subscribe to the manager but you connect one of its signals to one of your slots.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads

Comment: I thought about that, but what if I dont want the CameraManager to be a Q_OBJECT?

Comment: ...you just wrap it in an adapter that is a `Q_OBJECT`.

Comment: Or, you can use Boost signals. It is very useful when you don't want to use QObject in you business logic.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, using signals/slots between QObjects in different threads should take care of the issue "automagically."

Barring that, and assuming `MainWindow/ICameraAddedConsumer` is a `QObject`, one idea could be to use something like:

[`QMetaObject::invokeMethod(consumer, "ConsumeCameraAdded", Qt::QueuedConnection, ...)`](http://%20https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod)

where `consumer` is a pointer to the `MainWindow/ICameraAddedConsumer` instance.

There's [`QWaitCondition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html) but I'm not sure that makes sense in this case (though it could be adapted I suppose).

Otherwise... don't create the widget in `ConsumeCameraAdded()` but set some flag there (and return) and then use a `QTimer` or `QObject::timerEvent()` to periodically check the flag and create widget if it is set. Unfortunately I'm pretty sure you will not be able to create or start a timer within `ConsumeCameraAdded()` itself because of threading issues.